# How would I change the code to work with a table instead of body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to jquery, and I tried researching before hand but found nothing helpful. What I'm trying to do is change the code from working on the entire body to working on a single specific table and I'm not sure how I would go about that. What the code does is this: when you click on the screen a popup opens and if you click anywhere again it closes. I tried simply changing the word "body" to "table" and it opened when I clicked on the table but wouldn't close.

Here's the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("body").click(function(){
          $(".overlay, .popup").fadeToggle(); 
}); 
});
</script>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}
.overlay {
    position:absolute;
    display:none; 

    /* color with alpha transparency */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);

    /* stretch to screen edges */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.popup {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;

    /* center it ? */
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
    margin-top: -75px;
}
</style>
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="popup">Some popup text</div>
<p>Some content text (click anywhere to toggle overlay)</p>
```

Jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vgg6q8uL/

Here's the code of what I tried:

Here's the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("table").click(function(){
          $(".overlay, .popup").fadeToggle(); 
}); 
});
</script>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}
.overlay {
    position:absolute;
    display:none; 

    /* color with alpha transparency */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);

    /* stretch to screen edges */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.popup {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;

    /* center it ? */
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
    margin-top: -75px;
}
</style>
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="popup">Some popup text</div>
<p>Some content text (click anywhere to toggle overlay)</p>

<table width="50" height="50" bgcolor="red">
<tr>
<td>
click on me
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here's the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/k6L6x3yv/

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I can't see a `table` in your code.

Comment: If you use `"table"` as a selector, you'd need to click on the table again to close the popup. That might not actually be an option, since it looks like the `.overlay` element obscures the rest of the page. Might be better to have two event handlers: one for the table to show the overlay, and another on the entire body to close it.

Comment: I'll add what I tried to the question.

Comment: The fiddle is working as expected, right?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist do you know any way of getting around that?

Comment: @AldourCheng for the shown code yes, but I'm trying to get it to work for a specific table.

Comment: @Mortuux Yes, edited my comment. Two distinct event handlers, one to open (on clicking the table), another to close when you click anywhere (except possibly the table?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully this makes sense. What was happening is the overlay would cover everything, but the overlay is still within body so it worked with body being set.

Instead just make it so .overlay is also toggled.

http://jsfiddle.net/vgg6q8uL/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".activator, .overlay").click(function(){
          $(".overlay, .popup").fadeToggle(); 
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason why the overlay will not diaper when you change the jQuery click to table, is the overlay is covering the table; therefore making it not click able. You can `bind` a `click` event to the overlay to make the overlay fade out. check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vgg6q8uL/6/

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vgg6q8uL/10/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("table,.overlay, .popup").click(function(){
          $(".overlay, .popup").fadeToggle(); 
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to split up the functions between the `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` because your triggers are different for each. Try setting up the `fadeOut()` on the overlay like so:

```
   $("table").on('click', function () {
        $(".overlay, .popup").fadeIn();
        $(".overlay").on('click', function () {
            $(".overlay, .popup").fadeOut();
            $(this).off();
        });
    });
```

here is an example: [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vgg6q8uL/7/)
Also, using `.on('click',...)` is preferred over `.click(...)` because I can remove the event listener easily with the `.off()` and prevent listening for it when unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for : http://jsfiddle.net/vgg6q8uL/9/

Popup show only on table click and hide on click anywhere.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("table").click(function(){

          $(".overlay, .popup").fadeToggle(); 
         return false;
     }); 
    $("body").click(function () {
        if($(".popup:visible").length > 0)
        {
            $(".overlay, .popup").fadeToggle(); 
        }

    });
});
```